# Is it possible to have different javascript files for debugging and production in web application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'd like to have different versions of .js javascript files in my ASP.NET WebForms application (VS 2008):

- the full-blown version, which comments and so on
- the minified version, for production

Is there a way to automatically get the full-blown version while debugging and the minified version when the application is deployed to production? I don't mind if the answer is a hack.

Is it possible in VS 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using the SquishIt library.

- Download : https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/downloads
- Walkthrough : http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher

Allows you to keep your CSS and JavaScript in multiple files for local development and publishes a single minified file for production.

**EDIT:** This tool allows to define programmatically a list of files to minify. The code that defines this list is embedded in code blocks in the .aspx file or MVC view. At run time two things happen:

- a minifed file is dynamically created
- a link to the dynamically created minified file is created in the final rendered HTML

But, if `#debug` is defined, instead of doing so, the code renders the links to the original files in the output, so that the original version of the files can be used for debugging.

It supports CSS and javascript minfication.

For further info, follow the above links.

Answer (score 9):

Of course it is possible, but the question here is "**how you going to set it up.**"

I start with the key here that is the `DEBUG` definition. So let say that you like to set it up on the page.

So on page you can do something like:

```
<% #if DEBUG %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<% #else %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<% #endif %>
```

Alternative, you can use a Literal and make this switch on code behind.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtScripts" EnableViewState="false" />
```

and

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        txtScripts.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js\"></script>";
#else
        txtScripts.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>";
#endif
    }
```

Other way is to use a handler and read all the javascript files and make minified using code, and use again the same key DEBUG to send the one or the other version.

Personally I use the MS Ajax MInified
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxMinDocumentation.ashx
I read all my javascript files, make them one file, and use this parameters to minified them or not.

```
Minifier MyMin = new Minifier();
CodeSettings cs = new CodeSettings();
#if DEBUG
    cs.MinifyCode = false;
    cs.OutputMode = OutputMode.MultipleLines;
    cs.PreserveFunctionNames = true;
    cs.RemoveFunctionExpressionNames = false;
    cs.RemoveUnneededCode = false;
    cs.StripDebugStatements = false;
#else                   
    cs.MinifyCode = true;
    cs.OutputMode = OutputMode.SingleLine;              
#endif
Write(MyMin.MinifyJavaScript(AllMyJavascript, cs))
```

Comment: +1 great answer. I just can't figure out which kind of handler to implement to use the code with the `Minifier` object. But i've chosen the other answer. If you don't know what SquishIt is all about you should have a look: it generates dynamically minified files from a list of files to minify, and exposes the link to the generate file. But if #debug isn't defined the links to the original files are created. It's a great solution. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @JotaBe an .ashx handler. Is not so simple, need some checks and cache, but this is the general idea. By the way, I think the new 4.5 do that with a new library - to read all the js from a directory send send them as one, like the squishlt library domdenoit mention.

Comment: When using your first option, how would I start my site from within Visual Studio in order to actually see it use the minified version? I've tried starting with `F5` and `Ctrl+F5`, and also by setting the solution configuration to Release. In all situations, the generated HTML references the full version.

Comment: @comecme You can set the DEBUG version on the web.config as `<compiler compilerOptions="/D:DEBUG,TRACE" >` If you won the release, you do not set this options you set `<compilation debug="false" >`

Comment: @Aristos: thanks! So, even though starting with `Ctrl+F5` will unset DEBUG inside the code behind, the DEBUG for the .aspx is determined by web.config. Seems illogical to me.